# Организация классов в Java

Tags: java, классы, структуры, организация

Есть класс MyList, который представляет из себя организацию однонаправленного, линейного списка с методами получения данных. Так же есть класс MyListElement, который представляет собой элемент линейного списка (содержит информационное поле и "ссылку" next), имеет методы доступа и установки полей. Оба класса объявлены, как public и вот тут появляется проблема: можно создать экземпляр класса MyListElement в любом блоке самого модуля, но как факт этот класс нужен только для MyList, чтобы реализовывать сами элементы линейного списка. Нарушается принцип инкапсуляции. Подскажите, как можно было бы правильно организовать структуру, с точки зрения языка и профессионального программирования, чтобы не нарушался принцип инкапсуляции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Инкапсуляция - это не параноидальное желание скрыть все ото всех; нет ничего плохого в том факте, что что-то лежит в публичном доступе. Конкретно ваш случай решается либо через область видимости package-local, либо (что выглядит куда приличнее) через вложенный статический класс:

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    public void add(E element) {
        Element<E> e = new Element(element);
        tail.setNext(e);
        ...
    }
    ...

    private static class Element<E> {

         private Element<E> next;
         private E value;

         public Element(E value) {
             this.value = value;
         }

         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и думал, что нужно делать вложенный класс. Есть еще такой вопрос: я правильно понимаю, что такие классы, как и приватные методы, не документируют? В книге прочитал, что есть такая рекомендация, не документировать всё, что нельзя будет использовать из вне.

Comment: @DarkZ Есть вероятность, что этот участок кода будут дорабатывать без вас, устанавливать такое ограничение не стоит.